# CSS to scale img element's image to match containing button element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way in CSS to scale an img element's image to match the containing button element?

In this example, I would like the image to be centered on the button and scaled suitably for the size of the button.  In fact they are neither suitably scaled nor aligned.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button img element scaling</title>
        <style type="text/css">
         div.container {
             display: flex;
             justify-content: center;
         }
         button {
             min-width: 20px;
             max-width: 20px;
             flex-basis: 20px;
             height: 20px;
         }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <button>
                <img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/materialicons/clear/v6/24px.svg" />
            </button>
            <button>
                <img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/materialicons/clear/v6/24px.svg" />
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I believe it is possible using divs instead of button elements, but I'm asking about button elements (because it's nice semantically to have a button be a button, and because the buttons I have are already styled).

I also believe there are alternative ways to approach this using background images, but since here the image is not just decoration but has semantic meaning, I'd like to use an img (and later add an alt attribute).

The example uses flex, but the problem doesn't seem to be specific to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display flex on the button itself seems to do the trick

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button img element scaling</title>
        <style type="text/css">
         div.container {
             display: flex;
             justify-content: center;
         }
         button {
             min-width: 20px;
             max-width: 20px;
             flex-basis: 20px;
             height: 20px;
             display: flex;
             align-items: center;
             justify-content: center;
         }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <button>
                <img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/materialicons/clear/v6/24px.svg" />
            </button>
            <button>
                <img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/materialicons/clear/v6/24px.svg" />
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**edit**

incase it needs to grow to the button size aswell, you can add `width="100%" height="100%"` on the image to make it scale.

it would look like this:

```
<img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/materialicons/clear/v6/24px.svg" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use object-fit in your css -> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Comment: I did try that; it seemed to work for div elements, but not for button elements